# Is there a way for MongoTemplate to return the subdocment keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to access the mongo database which contains sub-elements within the collection and would like to retrieve the keys of those sub-elements for use in later queries.

What I mean is:

```
List<DBObject> results = mongoTemplate.find(query, DBObject.class, collection);
```

And my collection contains:

```
{
    "id"   : "12344",
    "name" : "Joe",
    "age"  : "25",
    "agent" : {
        "status" : "superduper",
     }
}
```

So in my List of DBObject's I would like to see a keySet() containing not only `id`, `name`, `age` but also `agent.status` - NOT `agent`

If this can't be done, what's the best way to go about grabbing `agent.status`?

Thanks

Comment: this is possible: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specific-fields-in-embedded-documents

Comment: @Astro thanks for that.  But I have to pull back everything from the database.  In fact it's a findAll.  What's worse is the database and collection can change since this is a library so it's possible that this structure may even be flat.  But at least this is a worst case scenario for now.